# get current terminal display text from another terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, terminal

I've started a job in a terminal that will print some data to the screen that I need. I know I should have used screen or told the terminal to log to a script but I did not. Also, I do not have the option to stop and restart the process. Still, I want to be able to SSH into the box and grab the text from the terminal display once the job is done. Is this possible?

(Linux 3.2.0-55-generic #85-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux)

Comment: Once the computer has sent the text to the terminal, the only thing that "remembers" the text is the terminal program itself. Your best bet is probably to use a screenshot utility to get an image of the terminal window.

Comment: @kenster is that something i can do remotely?

Comment: What operating system is hosting the display where this terminal program is displaying? Is it putty on windows? some X-based program on linux? Something else?

Comment: System info included in the question in parentheses. Using default terminal in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using virtual consoles.  The /dev/vcs* and /dev/vcsa* devices corresponds to the /dev/tty* devices (the virtual terminals).  /dev/tty1 should have a matching /dev/vcs1 and vcsa1.

As root, you can cat these devices (e.g. cat /dev/vcs1), and see what's on the corresponding tty.  Note that the output does not contain  newline  characters,  so some processing may be required, for example:

```
fold -w 80 /dev/vcs1 > screendump.txt
```

See [man vcsa](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?vcsa%204)